# iOS app crashing when trying to log out of Facebook using FBSDK for swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift4, fbsdk

I'm having trouble using the FBSDK for my iOS app. Logging in seems to work fine but logging out immediately crashes the app.

I'm using Swift 4 and FBSDK version 4.4. I suspect that the documentation I found online and other solutions that I googled were not using the same exact versions because nothing I've found has worked for me. Here is my app delegate code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let handled: Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[.annotation])
        return handled
    }
```

And here is my logout code:

```
@IBAction func btnFbLogoutClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let loginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logOut()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "UnwindToLogin", sender: self)
    }
```

It crashes and closes the app on logOut() and does not perform the segue. If anyone is using the same versions of FBSDK and Swift I would appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Do you have an error crash log in console?

Comment: @Larme it just says this: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Full error message? There is nothing above?

Comment: @Larme no it just stops in the App Delegate file with that error or crashes the app with no error message

Answer (score -1):

You should add missing method in Appdelegate and follow my button action code. It's working for me. Hope it will be working for you.

```
  import UIKit
  import FBSDKCoreKit

  @UIApplicationMain
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
     var window: UIWindow?
     func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {    
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }
    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
     }
  }

 //MARK: FacebookLogin Button
 @IBAction func btnFacebookLoginClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logOut()
    fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web //Without safari Browser
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")){
                self.getFBUserData()
                fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        }else if result.isCancelled {
        print("Cancelled")
    }
    })
}
```

Comment: This answer does not explain anything. You should add comments to show what you are doing and why. Code only answers are not helpful.

Comment: @Jamil this does not work for me, but my login button is also on a different page from my logout button. Does that make a difference? I would also like to know what these functions are supposed to do